# How can I use jQuery to set a div to be visible?

Tags: jquery

I have a div as part of a page that is rendered like this:

```
<div id="productdiv" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

Upon a certain event, I want this div to become visible.

The following does not work:

```
$("#productdiv").show();
```

What will work?

Comment: Have you tried setting your div to display:none rather than visibility:hidden? I think that might do what you expect.

Comment: $('#productdiv').show();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try something like this

```
$("#productdiv").css("visibility","visible");
```

or use this to set multiple **CSS** properties for **ALL matched** elements:

```
   $("#productdiv").css({"visibility":"visible","font-size":"50px"});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;`

**Example**

Replace this :

```
<div id="productdiv" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

With

```
<div id="productdiv" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The show method works for the display property, not the visibility property. Use, `.css('visibility', 'visible')`...

Answer (score 0):

The `show` function sets the `display` css attribute. Use `$("#productdiv").css("visibility", "visible");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#productdiv:hidden').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.asdf').click(function(){
    $("#productDiv").css('visibility','visible');
});
```